# Sueper button is not working

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Despite the keyboard on screen show that Super button is pushed, when I try the commons Ubuntu shortcuts , Super button is not works.
I actually tried to setup  different keyboard shortcuts but Super is not recognized

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Which version of Ubuntu you are at? And what are the model name of the computer and keyboard? Which language you are using on the computer?